# Github OAuth using Firebase - how to get user's username

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I followed the Firebase's guide on how to authenticate with Github. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/github-auth

The return result from Firebase's signInWithRedirect method contains the user's **displayName** and **email**, etc. However, it doesn't seem to contain user's '**login**' username which is the key for invoking most of Github's API calls.

I am sure there is a way to get it, but I just can't seem to find any documentation. Does anyone happen to know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using [Github's API](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#3-use-the-access-token-to-access-the-api) to get user's username with accessToken.

Comment: Hey, it's been over an year, but it would be great if you could share the code snippet as well :)

Did you use the search API with the email field as the search item, because I couldn't find any direct api to get username given the email.

Comment: Also the link you've originally linked to no longer exists, just redirects to the main API page!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the user's GitHub username through a parameter called "username" (see more here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/blob/master/docs/v1/providers/github.md)

Note: firebase-simple-login was deprecated on October 3th, 2014

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am afraid the repository is deprecated. I guess one can still use it to get the 'username', but is there any way to use firebase's new API to get it? BTW, I am currently following the auth guide here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/github-auth

Comment: firebase-simple-login was deprecated October 3, 2014

Answer (score 1):

You can use get the authenticated user from this [GitHub's api](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user)

Or if you use [octokit javascript rest api client](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js), you can do something like this

```
octokit = new Octokit({auth: userAccessToken }) 
octokit.users.getAuthenticated()
                        .then(result => {
                            console.log(result.data.login) // this is the username
                        })
```

Note: you'll get accessToken after GitHub <-> firebase login

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the username in additionalUserInfo:

```js
const githubProvider = new firebaseClient.auth.GithubAuthProvider();

githubProvider.addScope('read:user');
githubProvider.setCustomParameters({
  allow_signup: false,
});

firebaseClient.initializeApp(clientConfig);

async function submit() {
    try {
      const response = await firebaseClient
        .auth()
        .signInWithPopup(githubProvider);

      console.log(response.additionalUserInfo);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can use email to do authorized requests insted username:

Username: mayGitHubEmail@mail.com
Password: accessToken

[like this with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTzj7.png)

[body sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJfvC.png)

Here is a sample using class func in Swift using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON pods:

```swift
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

enum NetworkError: Error {
    case url
    case server
    case auth
}

class GistServices {
    
    class func makePostApiCall(toUrl path: String, withBody parameters: JSON, usingCredentials: Bool = false) -> Result<Data?, NetworkError> {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: path) else {
            return .failure(.url)
        }
        if let email = UserAuthSingleton.shared.get(), let password = UserAuthSingleton.shared.getUserToken() {
            var result: Result<Data?, NetworkError>!
            
            var request = AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
            
            if(usingCredentials){
                let credentialData = "\(email):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
                
                let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString()
                
                
                let headers = [HTTPHeader(name: "Authorization", value: "Basic \(base64Credentials)"),
                               HTTPHeader(name: "Accept", value: "application/json"),
                               HTTPHeader(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/json")]
                
                
                
                request = AF.request(url, method: .post,  parameters: parameters.dictionaryValue, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: HTTPHeaders(headers))
            }
            request
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
                .response { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .failure(_):
                    result = .failure(.server)
                case .success(let value):
                    result = .success(value)
                }
            }
            return result
        }
        return .failure(.auth)
    }
}
```